# Include of iostream leads to different binary

Tags: c++, assembly, iostream

Compiling the following code

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

gives the assembly

```
main:
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        ret
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oQvRDd

If now `iostream` is included

```
#include <iostream>   
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

this assembly is created.

```
main:
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, %edi
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        movl    $__dso_handle, %edx
        movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, %esi
        movl    $_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev, %edi
        addq    $8, %rsp
        jmp     __cxa_atexit
```

Full optimization is turned on (-O3).
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EtrEX8

Can someone explain, why including an unused header changes the binary. What is `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:`?

Comment: The C++ design philosophy of *What you don't use, you don't pay for* ([Foundations of C++, p. 4](http://www.stroustrup.com/ETAPS-corrected-draft.pdf)) is a lofty goal, however there are some situations in which it is not attained. There are quite a few things that can bloat a C++ binary and yet be useless, and you've stumbled upon one of them. Do note that the language itself does not mandate them; those are failures of tools to optimize them away.

Comment: @MatthieuM. - To be fair, this can be called a [programming error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079248/include-of-iostream-leads-to-different-binary/52079357#comment91126611_52079357). Kinda like making a a function needlessly virtual. The goal can be better expressed as "you don't pay for what you don't ask". It's the programmer that needs to know what they are asking for.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I disagree. If the optimizer removes any instance of calls to `cout` because it proved the branches were never taken; you still will end-up with those useless leftovers. If you had used `printf` instead, then it would be fully eliminated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Each translation unit that includes `<iostream>` contains a copy of `ios_base::Init` object:

```
static ios_base::Init __ioinit;
```

This object is used to initialize the standard streams (`std::cout` and its friends). This method is called [Schwarz Counter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter) and it ensures that the standard streams are always initialized before their first use (provided `iostream` header has been included).

That function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main` is code the compiler generates for each translation unit that calls the constructors of global objects in that translation unit and also arranges for the corresponding destructor calls to be invoked at exit. This code is invoked by the C++ standard library start-up code before `main` is called.

Comment: Initialize, and (perhaps more importantly) flush them before normal termination.

Comment: Interestingly, no storage for `__ioinit` itself is allocated.  At the same time I wonder why the constructor is not in marked comdat.  Is this code really duplicated in every single translation unit that uses `iostream`?  Seems really inefficient.

Comment: @fuz `_ZStL8__ioinit` is the storage for `__ioinit`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Ah, I see.  Even less efficient.  One useless byte wasted just because there is no better way to do a singleton initialisation in C++.

Comment: @fuz - C++17's inline variable definitions can.

Comment: @StoryTeller is defining the stream (cout for example) as inline variable inside the iostream header making the whole schwartz/niffty counter obsolete? and is it even superior? because we can still make the schwartz counter fail

Comment: This is why you should include `<istream>` and/or `<ostream>` instead of `<iostream>` in translation units that don't need to refer to cin, cout, cerr, wcin, wcout, and wcerr.

Comment: @phön - I don't know. But it sounds like a great topic for a language lawyer question. Personally, I don't think it's a silver bullet, but inline variables do seem promising.

Answer (score 23):

Including the `iostream` header has the effect of adding the definition of a static `std::ios_base::Init` object. The constructor of this static object initializes the standard stream objects `std::cout`, `std::cerr` and so forth.

The reason it's done is to avoid the static initialization order fiasco. It ensures the stream objects are properly initialized across translation units.

Comment: In other words, link-time optimisation _may_ be able to elide this, right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Theoretically, and hopefully.

Comment: Even with link-time optimization, I don't think the compiler has enough information to understand that `__ioinit` is superfluous in a translation unit that makes no reference to any of the standard streams.