# How come gcc 13.1 does not generate any code when including <iostream>?

Tags: c++, gcc, code-generation, iostream

Let's say I have a very simple program like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    return 12;
}
```

When compiling this program with gcc (from gcc-4.x to gcc-12.x), the generated code is something like this (check [online on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/q6v9nnqfP)):

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, 12
        pop     rbp
        ret
__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        jne     .L5
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 65535
        jne     .L5
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        call    __cxa_atexit
.L5:
        nop
        leave
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     esi, 65535
        mov     edi, 1
        call    __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

That is acceptable based on the fact that the `<iostream>` header file contains a static variable of `ios_base::Init` object (See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079248/include-of-iostream-leads-to-different-binary) for more info).

But starting from gcc-13.1, it seems that including of `<iostream>` header has no effect on the generated code. So, the question is, how gcc-13.1 manages to do that? Is it due to a change in the `iostream` header file? Or it is an optimization of gcc in version 13.1?

Comment: I'd assume it's an optimization since that global variable is used nowhere

Comment: https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2023/04/03/leaner-libstdc-gcc-13

Comment: @Vivick Then `ios_base::Init` would've never worked in the first place, since that variable would always be unused.

Comment: @Vivick Any references about this optimization on gcc 13.1? I cannot find anything.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the reference. It is exactly what I was searching for. You may write it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @TonySalimi I've never really researched how that attribute works. I'd gladly read a more detailed answer myself. :P